# Convert duration (string column) to seconds PySpark

Tags: string, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Can I convert easily a string column (with time duration) to seconds in PySpark?

Is there any function that does this directly? I would avoid to multiplicate each part of my string for seconds.

`Input`

| id | duration |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 00 00:00:34 |
| 2 | 00 00:04:37 |
| 3 | 120 00:04:37 |
| ... | ... |

**NOTE:**

*Id 1 -> 0 days, 0 hours, 0 minutes, 34 seconds*

*Id 2 -> 0 days, 0 hours, 4 minutes, 37 seconds*

*Id 3 -> 120 days, 0 hours, 4 minutes, 37 seconds*

`Output`

| id | duration |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 34 |
| 2 | 277 |
| 3 | ... |
| ... | ... |

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get day,min,hour and seconds from duration column by applying `split` and then sum up the corresponding seconds to get desired result.

```
df = # input

df.withColumn("duration", split("duration", "\\s+")) \
    .withColumn("time", split(col("duration").getItem(1), ':')) \
    .select(col("id"),
            ((col("duration").getItem(0).cast("int") * 86400) +
             (col("time").getItem(0).cast("int") * 3600) +
             (col("time").getItem(1).cast("int") * 60) +
             (col("time").getItem(2))).cast("long").alias("duration")
            ).show()

+---+--------+
| id|duration|
+---+--------+
|  1|      34|
|  2|     277|
|  3|10368277|
+---+--------+
```

Comment: It works! Thank u! I didn't know getItem function!

Answer (score 0):

you can do it easily by using `unix_timestamp` but I recommend doing small processing to remove days part (I didn't catch why it is not working with it) otherwise it working perfectly in `HH:mm:ss` format.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, unix_timestamp
df.withColumn('seconds', unix_timestamp(col('duration'), 'HH:mm:ss')).show()
```

the output will be like this:

```
+---+--------+-------+
| id|duration|seconds|
+---+--------+-------+
|  1|00:00:34|     34|
|  2|00:04:37|    277|
|  3|00:04:37|    277|
+---+--------+-------+
```